# Booting in insecure mode message despite secure boot being enabled

Tags: boot, secure-boot

I don't really know where I messed up with my system, but since the past few hours I've been getting this message on booting up my laptop. This started happening after I disabled secure boot using:

```
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

I also disabled secure boot from my BIOS. However, after about 20-30 minutes, I re-enabled secure boot, both from my BIOS, as well as from the terminal using

```
sudo mokutil --enable-validation
```

Then, I rebooted my system, got the MOK management blue screen.

However, after 10 seconds the screen disappeared as usual to continue the boot process, but then again, the first thing that popped up was the 'Booting in insecure mode' message. I even tried re-installing Ubuntu, but that didn't solve the problem either.

Note that I use a proprietary graphics driver (NVIDIA), but have been using this since the beginning, and I had't come across this message on boot-up before this. Also, my system is a single-boot Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS at the moment (always has been, got rid of Windows).

Please help me with some fix on this. It's really annoying to see the message on boot-up.